# WP order ASC in custom author loop

Tags: wp-query

My current author list shows authors with posts only, but its not ordered by `ASC` and its not working. Any ideas?

```
<ul class="authorlist">
<?php
// displays all users with their avatar and their posts (titles)
$blogusers = get_users_of_blog();
if ($blogusers) {
    foreach ($blogusers as $bloguser) {
        $user = get_userdata($bloguser->user_id);

        $args=array(
            'author' => $user->ID,
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'post_status' => 'publish'
        );
        $my_query = null;
        $my_query = new WP_Query($args);

        if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
            echo '<li>';
            echo '<a href="'.get_author_posts_url( $user->ID ).'">';
            if ( has_wp_user_avatar($user->ID) ) {
                echo '<span class="avaterimage">' . get_wp_user_avatar($user->ID, 128) . '</span>';
            } else {
                echo '<span class="avaterimage"><img src="'.get_template_directory_uri().'/images/empty_avatar_256x256.png'.'"></span>';
            }
            echo '<p>' . $user->user_firstname.' '.$user->user_lastname . '</p>';
            echo '</a>';
            echo '</li>';
        }

        wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
    }
}
?>
</ul>
```

- The reason I'm using this is WP default `wp_list_authors` has no avatar image option.

Comment: How old a source did you copy this from? [`get_users_of_blog()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users_of_blog) has been deprecated a long time...

Comment: yea i dont know lol, when I use get_users it shows nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to @Rarst answer, there are a couple of other problems in your code.

As stated, `get_users_of_blog()` has been depreciated. You've said that you did try [`get_users()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users), but it did not work. The reason for that is, the returned objects have changed with the function. You should do a `var_dump` to see what objects are returned and are valid to use

Doing something like this

```
<?php
$blogusers = get_users();
?><pre><?php var_dump($blogusers); ?></pre><?php
```

produces something like

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  object(WP_User)#307 (7) {
    ["data"]=>
    object(stdClass)#208 (10) {
      ["ID"]=>
      string(1) "4"
      ["user_login"]=>
      string(8) "NAME WITHHELD"
      ["user_pass"]=>
      string(34) "$P$BUisddOXmHJTE8i1vB/a1WZIy4KazDbD/1"
      ["user_nicename"]=>
      string(8) "chantell"
      ["user_email"]=>
      string(26) "EMAIL WITHHELD"
      ["user_url"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["user_registered"]=>
      string(19) "2013-07-01 15:25:10"
      ["user_activation_key"]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["user_status"]=>
      string(1) "0"
      ["display_name"]=>
      string(15) "WITH HELD"
    }
    ["ID"]=>
    int(4)
    ["caps"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["subscriber"]=>
      bool(true)
    }
    ["cap_key"]=>
    string(15) "wp_capabilities"
    ["roles"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "subscriber"
    }
    ["allcaps"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["read"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["level_0"]=>
      bool(true)
      ["subscriber"]=>
      bool(true)
    }
    ["filter"]=>
    NULL
    etc.......................
```

This is also wrong

```
$user = get_userdata($bloguser->user_id);
```

`user_id` should be `ID` as you can see from the `var_dump`. Also, I think you are actually looking for [`get_user_meta`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta) as `get_userdata` returns the same values as `get_users`. Also, do a `var_dump` to see what objects are returned from `get_user_meta`

```
$user = get_user_meta($bloguser->ID);
?><pre><?php var_dump($user); ?></pre><?php
```

returns

```
array(14) {
  ["first_name"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "WITHELD"
  }
  ["last_name"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "WITHHELD"
  }
  ["nickname"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "WITHHELD"
  }
  ["description"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  ["rich_editing"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "true"
  }
  ["comment_shortcuts"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "false"
  }
  ["admin_color"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "fresh"
  }
  ["use_ssl"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  ["show_admin_bar_front"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "true"
  }
  ["wp_capabilities"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(28) "a:1:{s:10:"subscriber";b:1;}"
  }
  ["wp_user_level"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  ["avatar_manager_avatar_type"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "gravatar"
  }
  ["twitter"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  ["facebook"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(12) "WITHHELD"
  }
}
```

This should get you going. Just another point, you should use `wp_reset_postdata()` to reset `WP_Query`, not `wp_reset_query()`

Comment: sorting works but avatars stopped showing, but w/e

Answer (score 1):

[`get_users_of_blog()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_users_of_blog/) is indeed deprecated and has SQL query hardcoded to sort by ID.

You need to use modern [get_users()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) function. It supports many arguments, including multiple ways to sort.